# Как удалить сущности из Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, jsx

Всем привет, осваиваю редакс, написал кейсы для добавления и удаления сущностей. Удаление не работает, логика вроде верная, берём весь `...state`, используем на нём метод `filter` которых возвращает новый массив, состоящий из элементов удовлетворяющих условию, т. е. из элементов не равных `action.name`. Таким образом мы удалили нужную сущность из массива + создали новый массив, а не мутировали старый, вроде всё верно, но почему не работает?

**reducer**

```
export default function reducer(state = initialState, action) {

    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_ITEM':
            return [
                ...state,
                {
                    name: action.name,
                    age: action.age
                }
            ];

        case 'DELETE_ITEM':
            return  [
                ...state,
                state.filter(name => name!== action.name),
            ];

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

render in App.js:

```
function ListOfUsers() {
        const listItems = users.map(function (value, index) {
            return (
                <div>
                    <li key={index}>{value.name}, {value.age}</li>
                    <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'DELETE_ITEM', name:value.name })}
                            className="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                        Удалить
                    </button>
                </div>
            )
        });
        return (
            <ul>{listItems}</ul>
        );
    }
```

state looks like:

```
const initialState = [
     {
        name: 'Theodore Roosevelt',
        age: 56
    },
];

export default initialState;
```

Answer (score 0):

Кароче я не знаю как, но работа метода `filter` остаётся загадкой. Если бы кто-то объяснил,  я был бы очеьн благодарен. Переделал с использованием конкат и слайс.

```
return  [
                ...state.slice(0, action.id).concat(state.slice(action.id + 1))
            ];
```